# How to make a table using bash shell?

Tags: bash, paste, txt

I have multiple text files that have their own column. I hope to combine them into one text file like a table not a long column.

I tried 'paste' and 'column', but it did not make the shape that I wanted.

When I used the paste with two text files, it made a nice table.

`paste height_1.txt height_2.txt > test.txt`

The trouble starts from three or more text files.

`paste height_1.txt height_2.txt height_3.txt > test.txt`

At a glance, it seems nice. But when I plot the each column in the text.txt file in gnuplot(`p "text.txt"`), I could find some unexpected graph different from the original file especially ***in its last part***.

[image]

The shape of the table is ruined in a strange way in the test.txt, causing the graph weird.

How could I make a well-structured table in the text file with bash shell?

Is it not useful to do this work with bash shell?

If yes, I will try this with python.

Height files are extracted from other *.csv files using awk.

Thank you so much for reading this question.

Comment: Do your CSVs contain any `"` character?

Comment: Yes, So I use this command when I abstract the data from *.csv: ```#awk -F "," '{print $7}' Pr-$i.csv | awk 'NR > 1' > height_$i.txt```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` with simple concatenation can take the records for as many files as you have and join them together in a single output file for further processing. You simply provide the multiple input files as the files for `awk` to read and then concatenate each record using `FNR` (file record number) as an index and then use the `END` rule to print the combined records from all files.

For example, given 3 data files, e.g. `data1.txt` - `data3.txt` each with an integer in each row, e.g.

```
$ cat data1.txt 
1
2
3
```

```
$ cat data2.txt 
4
5
6
```

(`7-9` in `data3.txt`, and presuming you have an equal number of records in each input file)

You could do:

```bash
awk '{a[FNR]=(FNR in a) ? a[FNR] "\t" $1 : $1} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt
```

(using a `tab` above with `"\t"` for the separator between columns of the output file -- you can change to suit your needs)

The result of the command above would be:

```
1       4       7
2       5       8
3       6       9
```

(**note:** this is what you would get with `paste data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt`, but presuming you have input that is giving `paste` problems, `awk` may be a bit more flexible)

Or using a `","` as the separator, you would receive:

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

If your data file has more fields than a single integer and you want to compile all fields in each file, you can assign `$0` to the array instead of the first field `$1`.

Spaced and formatted in multi-line format (for easier reading), the same `awk` script would be

```bash
awk '
  { 
    a[FNR] = (FNR in a) ? a[FNR] "\t" $1 : $1
  }
  END {
    for (i in a)
      print a[i]
  }
' data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt
```

Look things over and let me know if I misunderstood your question, or if you have further questions about this approach.

Comment: David. Thank you so much for your detailed answer. When I use your code, I can get the flipped result:3 2 1 6 5 4 9 8 7 (please imagine table 3 by 3 structure).

Comment: a[FNR] = (FNR in a) ? a[FNR] "\t" $1 : $1. How can I understand this part? I know the ```\t``` (delimiter is 'tab') and ```FNR``` ( the number of record in the current file).

Comment: `FNR` is the current record (line) number in each file. The *ternary* is a short-hand `if-else` in a form `test ? if_true : if_false`, so  `(FNR in a) ? a[FNR] "\t" $1 : $1` just say if the index exists in array `a[]` (true), it's not the first, so add a tab before concatenating this element, otherwise (false) just append the field itself as the first.

Comment: @Rankin I really appreciate your help with a neat example. I will try more and leave message.